# Jmeter Root ca certificate

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, root-certificate

I am new to jmeter. I followed steps as mentioned in [this link](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf). After that I tried to install a Root CA Certificate which installed it succesfully.

I am still facing same problem when I click the start button. Please can anyone suggest to me what to do further?

Please Find attached screen shot for reference:

[image]

Comment: Please do read the instructions on how to ask questions. And use the preview feature to format your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not an issue. Jmeter will prompt this .You can just click ok and continue recording.It will just use the available Root CA certificate.